# Java Script. После одного блока не переходит к другой части кода

Tags: javascript

Доходит только до 12 строки  и не переходит к следующей проверке, получается у пользователя есть три попытки ввести правильный пороль

```js
let login1 = prompt("Введите логин:");

const passw = '123456'

if (login1 === 'Admin'){ 

    let pass = prompt('Введите пороль:');

    if (pass === passw){
        console.log( 'Добро пожаловать админ!' );
    }else if(pass !== passw){
        console.log('Неверный пороль');

}else if (login1 === 'Admin'){

    let pass = prompt('Введите пороль:')

    if (pass === passw){
        console.log( 'Добро пожаловать админ!' );
    }else{
        console.log( 'Неверный пароль');
    }
}else if (login1 === 'Admin'){

    let pass = prompt('Введите пороль:')

    if (pass === passw){
        console.log( 'Добро пожаловать админ!' );
    }else{
        console.log('Вы три раза не правильно ввели пароль обновите страницу и попробуйте заново')
    }
}else if (login1 !== 'Admin'){
    console.log( 'вы неправильно ввели логин попробуйте заново' )
}
```

Comment: а где в коде 12 строка?

Comment: Так у вас одинаковые условия... Я бы добавил счётчик попыток. И ошибка в снипите.

Comment: то есть поучается после первой if не переходит к след else if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно причина не в этом, но вы фигурную скобку пропустили, но правда на 9-й строчке, если считать чисто этому коду:

```
let login1 = prompt("Введите логин:");

const passw = '123456'

if (login1 === 'Admin'){

    let pass = prompt('Введите пароль:');

    if (pass === passw){
        console.log( 'Добро пожаловать админ!' );
    }else if(pass !== passw){
        console.log('Неверный пароль!');
    }  //////////////////Этой скобки у Вас не было.
}else if (login1 === 'Admin'){

    let pass = prompt('Введите пароль:')

    if (pass === passw){
        console.log( 'Добро пожаловать админ!' );
    }else{
        console.log( 'Неверный пароль!');
    }
}else if (login1 === 'Admin'){

    let pass = prompt('Введите пароль:')

    if (pass === passw){
        console.log( 'Добро пожаловать админ!' );
    }else{
        console.log('Вы три раза не правильно ввели пароль обновите страницу и попробуйте заново')
    }
}else if (login1 !== 'Admin'){
    console.log( 'Неверный логин!' )
}
```

P.S. И да действительно, зачем столько повторяющегося кода?

Вот на мое мнения практически готовый код.

А если console.log заменить на alert, выглядит прикольнее. Но тут на вкус и цвет, как говорится.

UPD. Я что то не обратил внимания, что вы написали, что у пользователя всего 3 попытки. Подкорректировал код.

```js
let login,
pass,
temp = 3,
i = 1;
const loginw = 'Admin',
passw = '123456';

login1 = prompt('Введите логин:');

while (login1 !== loginw) {
if (login1 == null) {
    break;
}
console.log('Неверный логин!');
login1 = prompt('Введите логин:');
}
if (login1 == null) {
console.log('Вы отменили ввод логина!');
}

if (login1 === loginw) {
pass = prompt('Введите пароль:');


    while (pass !== passw) {
        if (pass == null) {
            break;
        }
        if (i < temp) {
            console.log('Неверный пароль! Осталось попыток:', temp - i, '.');
            pass = prompt('Введите пароль:');
        } else {
            console.log('Вы три раза неправильно ввели пароль, обновите страницу и попробуйте заново!');
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
if(pass === passw){
    console.log('Добро пожаловать, Админ!');
}
if (pass == null) {
    console.log('Вы отменили ввод пароля!');
}
}
```

Comment: я прохожу основы программирования и вот на днях перешли к js, и пока я только это знаю(   попробую  сделать счетчик как посоветовали  выше

Comment: @Енот, изучите циклы, на них это лучше всего делать. Ответ обновил, написал ваш пример на циклах, изучите и постарайтесь понять как это работает.

Comment: И используйте программы для кодинга с подсветкой синтаксиса, у вас бы показало ошибку с пропущенной скобкой.

Comment: @Denis, Я почти сразу исправил (не с той jsfiddle вкладки скопировал), наверное у вас просто не обновилось.

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось вот так, c alert  думаю было бы лучше, но в задании нужно чтобы выводилось в консоль:

```js
let login = prompt('Введите логин:')
const password = '123456';
let temp = 3,
    i = 1,
    input;
if (login === 'admin'){
    while (i <= temp) {
        input = prompt('Введите пароль:');
      
        if (input === null) {
          break;
        }
        
        if(password === input){
            console.log('Добро пожаловать админ!');
            break;
        } else if (i < temp) {
            console.log('Неверный пароль, у вас осталось', temp - i, 'попыток');
        } else {
            console.log('вы три раза не правильно ввели пароль обновите страницу и попробуйте заново');
        }
        
        i += 1;
      }
}else{
    console.log('вы неправильно ввели логин попробуйте заново')
}
```